# SQL Server 2012 Import and Export

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to Export data of few tables(TMP_TABLE1, TMP_TABLE2 so on) in a **single** file.
Then copy the file to a network path.
Then import the file in different database tables which has same table schema with different table names(TABLE1, TABLE2 so on)

All the tables have huge data.

**All these should be in T-SQL statement without using CLR. (No SSIS)**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since this is what SSIS was made to do, why can't you use it?

Comment: bcp will create single file for each table. But, our requirement is to create single file.

Comment: HLGEM, can we create single file for multiple tables using SSIS? Two databases are not on same network.